# OO class diagram for directory structure in UNIX || Windows

Tags: oop, class

This is an interview question which was asked to me (**Not** a homework question). I did give an answer but I wanted some professional opinion on whether the answer I gave was relevant or not. The proper question was:

**Construct an object oriented design for the UNIX || Windows directory structure?**

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How about posting your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Since we're talking OO, I assume he wants  you to concentrate on operations and structure.

A file and a directory would implement a common interface involving common operations but would also have their own operations.

A tree structure is involved, either the directories and files could be part of the tree or (as I'd probably do) the tree could be an external structure that references the files and directories.

I'd list the common operations in the interface (delete, getSize), the file-only operations (open, read, write, ...) in the file interface/object and the directory-only operations (changeDirectory, createChildDirectory, createFile) in the directory object.

The point, however, is that this is an open enough question to ensure that there is NO correct answer, rather it's a chance to evaluate how you "Think OO".  There are millions of good solutions, the bad ones would be ones that didn't identify methods and members as part of the object model.

It's also a good chance to show off your level of design skills--seeing if you can intelligently communicate your model to others (UML is amazingly helpful in this--working without UML can be like working without a common language when it comes to heavy modeling)

Answer (score 0):

The OO design will look basically the same as a dual linked tree with the ability to do cross-linking between nodes of two different types, hard and soft links.

There's also a bunch of complexity added in when you start to deal with permissions and meta-data, but those things are not specifically related to the directory structure.